# Why angular.injector(), when we have angular.module('moduleName', [<Dependencies If any>]);

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

everybody, As you can see the title, i have to confirm my understanding, that 
If we have :

```
angular.module('moduleName', [<Dependencies If any>]);
```

Then, do we really need this `angular.injector`, or is it just an another alternative. 
If there is any other advantages of using the `angular.injector`, please let me know.

I have couple of other doubts.

we can use $filter in controller to get the particular filter and use its functions if any.
1. so how to use/call filters in directives.
2. how to call one controller function in another controller, is it possible?

Please Let me know the advantage of using `angular.injector` over `angular.module('moduleName', [<Dependencies If any>]);` And when it is good/needed to use it. not the  implementaion of angular.injector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed it to get some services outside of the angular scope. For example my application is running on some legacy one. To change some parameters in the angular applicaion I needed to access an angular service from javascript outside of the angular. Then I used `angular.injector` to get the service.

```
injector = angular.element('#myangularDiv')).injector()
service = injector.get('theService')
```

Comment: looks like, you have catched my exact doubt, Can you please  describe what do you mean by "outside of the angular scope", If you give me an jsfiddle demo that will be great

Comment: I have used angular for a part of my application, basically its a `div` in the application. Outside of that div have nothing to do with angular. And I have some jquery code in that outside application.

Comment: Dear friend, can you please answer to my "couple of other doubts",

Comment: Those are totally difference questions , you may need to ask new questions ,but 
1. You can use filters in a directive, do you need to call it from a controller ? I think that is unnessary , controller does not need to know how the directives work.

2. You can't call it directly , but if you have it in the $scope, the $scopes are prototypically inherited , so you can call $parent $scope functions from the child. And the second way is to use 'broadcast/emit' and 'on' .

Comment: You may need to search for these keywords.